# Using Javascript variables in console.log as a reference

Tags: javascript, scope, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am now beginning my JavaScript path and have a question on usage of variables in Console.log

How can this code give me an error?

```js
var myAns = console.log(65/240);
console.log(100* +Number(myAns) );
```

If I am assigning output of the Console.log to the variable 'myAns' cannot I use that as a reference in another Console.log?

I searched elsewhere and saw that I needed to use another +operator right in front of the value (didnt work) or that I needed to input the Number() method in place (didnt work)

And the error I am getting is just: NaN

I believe I am Passing by reference, or is that the scope problem?

Comment: You're assigning the *return value* of the `console.log()` call to `myAns`. It does return `undefined`, not the text that it outputs to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I am assigning output of the Console.log to the variable 'myAns' cannot I use that as a reference in another Console.log?

In order to do this you would need to override the default `console.log()` function. Another, easier approach would be to do:

```
console.log(myAns = 65/240)
```

As in, console.log the result of assigning `65/240` to `myAns`.

Right now, you're doing `var myAns = console.log(65/240);` which, as Bergi mentioned, assigns the return value of `console.log(65/240)` (undefined) to `myAns`.

Comment: AH!
Its so obvious.

Yea the Syntax of the language is gonna take some time.

And do you know if I can have variable declaration in there?
Like so: console.log(var myAns = 65/240)
I know its proper to do so outside of it, but still.

Comment: @gabru678 you can, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning return value of "console.log" to myAns. It doesn't return the result of the calculation.  What you need is:

```
var myAns = 65/240;
console.log(myAns);
var myOtherAnswer = 100 * myAns;
console.log(myOtherAnswer);
```

Comment: Yup!

Thanks I was able to run it like so:<br/>


    `var myAns 
console.log(myAns=65/240);
console.log(100 * myAns  );`

Comment: @gabru678 Can you please upvote or accept my answer if it was helpful to you?

Comment: I did, would you mind upvoting the question itself in return, so that I can publicly contribute?

Answer (score 0):

IF a specific function has a return statement with a return value, then it will return that value once that function is being invoked from somewhere..

console.log just logs (displays) the value passed inside the parenthesis of the console.log(....) to the browser.

console.log() doesn't assigns a value back to a variable...
var value = console.log(100);
here it just displays the 100 on the browser but nothing will be assigned to value variable..